# GraphDB 9.3.0 (Win-Desktop) not starting

Tags: graphdb

I'm having troubles starting GraphDB Free 9.3 as a Windows desktop installation. When double clicking the .exe nothing happens. I don't even see any logs.
Please note that I previously had v8, which I deinstalled before installing v9. I also just tried to run the standalone server version and this works. What could be the problem with the desktop version?

My Java-Version:
openjdk 14 2020-03-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14+36-1461)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14+36-1461, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0):

A possible problem could be the Java version - the supported versions are up to JDK 11. Try changing the JDK or if this doesn't help take a look for any errors in  Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application. Also you could check for leftovers from the previous installation in \Users\your_user\AppData\Local\GraphDB Free

Comment: Okay, I figured the JDK version could be the problem. But I thought the desktop version comes with its own Java runtime, doesn't it? And why does the server-version work?
Unfortunately, switching my java version is not an option right now. I just tried deinstalling again and there are no "leftovers" in the directotries you mentioned. And EventViewer doesn't show any GraphDB logs.

Comment: And a colleague of mine had a similar problem with Java 8 (also with GraphDB 9.3.0, he didn't have an older version before)

Comment: Can you try to install older version of GraphDB (which worked before) again and see if this works now?

Comment: Sure, but where do I get an older version of GraphDB Free Desktop? The Maven Repo seems to only have older versions of the standalone standard and enterprise editions.

Comment: Could you please write an email to graphDB-support@ontotext.com with a request. Thanks!

Comment: I run the GDB Free installer and often upgrade, on Windows 10 64bit, without problem. Did you install from the Windows installer (it's the one that comes with its own java)? Which Windows do you have? Please try to Remove the old version first, then install a new version fresh.